# using fluent-nhibernate and traditionally hbm.xml together

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

So far I used this code to configure a session factory:

```
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.Configure();
        SessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Now I added some fluentNhibernate mapping classes, and used this code to configure:

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.Configure();
    SessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();


    SessionFactory = Fluently.Configure(configuration).Mappings(m =>
    {
        m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AttachmentLocaionMap>();
        m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AttachmentTypeMap>();
        m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AttachmentMap>();
     }).BuildSessionFactory();
```

But I guess it overrided the old xml mapping?
Now I want to **add** then to the **already existing** exmbeded resources xml-based mapping

How do I do this?

i saw this [blog](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2009/01/28/using-fluent-nhibernate-and-traditional-hbm-xml-files-in-the-same-project.aspx), but i don't want to add

> configuration.AddXmlFile( "Mappings/Insurance.hbm.xml" );
>   or
>   configuration.AddAssembly(...);

for each existing xml (as up till now I dodn't do it for each ebmbeded resource xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SessionFactory = Fluently.Configure(configuration).Mappings(m =>
{
    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AttachmentLocaionMap>();
    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AttachmentTypeMap>();
    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AttachmentMap>();
    m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SomeTypeFromYourAssemblyWithHbmMappings>()
 }).BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: I don't get it. that is the same as I do today

Comment: it works for me to get both going with m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf.  wonder if the difference has to do with what is coming up on your other question with us passing different configuration objects to fluent nhibernate.

Comment: That is not the same as yours @EladBenda.  Dave has `m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SomeTypeFromYourAssemblyWithHbmMappings>()` and you do not in your example.

Comment: Also do you truly have a mix of hbm mappings and fluent mappings?