# NHibernate define schema name

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to learn nhibernate. I understand how to create tables and entity map. But what I am not able to understand is how to create a new Schema using nHibernate.

I searched and found that using "ExposeConfiguration" you can create a Schema, but I unable to understand where do I provide my new Schema name.

Answer (score 0):

There is pretty clear documentation:

- [Database configuration](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Database-configuration)
- [Schema generation](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Getting-started)

So, Schema name you can basically set fore each class/table:

```
public MyEntityMap()
{
    ...
    Schema("mySchema");
}
```

Default could be set like this:

```
MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
  .UseOuterJoin()
  .DefaultSchema("dbo");
```

And this is some generation in place as well:

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
  return Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(
      SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
        .UsingFile("firstProject.db")
    )
    .Mappings(m =>
      m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
    .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
    .BuildSessionFactory();
}

private static void BuildSchema(Configuration config)
{
  // delete the existing db on each run
  if (File.Exists(DbFile))
    File.Delete(DbFile);

  // this NHibernate tool takes a configuration (with mapping info in)
  // and exports a database schema from it
  new SchemaExport(config)
    .Create(false, true);
}
```

EXTEND: How to create schema itself? *(e.g. `mySchemaName`)*

With HBM we can introduce this **embedded resource**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    namespace="MyNamespace" assembly="MyAssembly">

  <database-object>

    <create >
      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'mySchemaName')
      EXEC( 'CREATE SCHEMA mySchemaName' )
      GO
    </create>
    <drop></drop>
  </database-object>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

if this script would be included into fluent Configuration as first, it will create schema for us:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8278493/1679310

Comment: Schema("mySchema"); does this statement tells that this table belongs to this Scehma (but schema should already be present in DB). As far as I know, this statement does not create a new schema in the database. right ?

Comment: I see... now what you mean... I cannot remember how I solved that.

Comment: I found that. We can use special database objects to provide some special custom scripts... Hope this will help ;) Enjoy amazing NHibenrate

Comment: Ok, so what I understand that we can not create Schema from NHibernate, for that we need to create separate scripts. right ?

Comment: If you put it this way.. ok yes. But I prefer to say: class mapping is not related to "DB maitainance tasks" e.g. schema creation. BUT NHibernate provides "standard" way how to do that... Does it help? ;)